# Images are linked togheter with eclipse android app development

Tags: android, image, linked-list

I'm making a basic app for my android phone with eclipse. It's a simple basic app that provide information about a studentgroup. The app has 7 layout's: Home, contact's, history,...

On the home screen are 6 images, these images are clickable so you can go to the other layouts. But after a while i noticed some images are linked to each other.

**Example:** 
Here are the codes of 2 layout's, Homescreen and Praesidiumscreen. In these 2 layout's are 2 images linked. Notice that in the homescreen an image has an id IvRaf and in the Praesidium screen is an image IvRaf. If I want to change the ID of 1 image the ID of the other image also changes.

Someone knows how i can fix this? There are more images that have the same problem. If you need more information I can give it. Or i can send you the whole application.

This is the code of the **homescreen**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="409dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVRaf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bannerapp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVPraesidium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVRaf"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="clickPraesidium"
        android:src="@drawable/bannerpraesidium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVKalender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVPraesidium"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="clickKalender"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_kalender" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVGeschiedenis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVKalender"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="clickGeschiedenis"
        android:src="@drawable/bannergeschiedenis" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVKringlied"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVGeschiedenis"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="clickKringlied"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_kringlied2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVContact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVKringlied"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="clickContact"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_contact" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVSponsors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVContact"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="clickSponsors"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_sponsors" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is the code of the **Praesidiumscreen**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVTopBannerPraesidium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/topbanner_praesidium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVPraeses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iVRaf"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVTopBannerPraesidium"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Praeses: Rafaël Vercammen"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVInfoPraeses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVPraeses"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVPraeses"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Vulgo: &apos;Raf&apos;\nThuis-adres: Grasheide\nLid sinds 2011\nStudierichting: EM-Klima\nContact: praeses.mereta@gmail.com" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVDaan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iVRaf"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVInfoPraeses"
        android:layout_marginRight="237dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/daan" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVRaf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVTopBannerPraesidium"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="237dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/raf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVVice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVInfoPraeses"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVInfoPraeses"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Vice-Praeses: Daan Gybels"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVInfoVice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVVice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVVice"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Vulgo: &apos;Dakke&apos;\nKot-adres: Kot Leon\nThuis-adres: Tremelo\nLid sinds 2011\nStudierichting: OP\nContact: vicepraeses.mereta@gmail.com" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVTom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iVDaan"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iVDaan"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVInfoVice"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVAbactis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVInfoVice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVInfoVice"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Ab-Actis: Tom Hermans"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVInfoAbactis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVAbactis"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVAbactis"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Vulgo: &apos;Tommeke&apos;\nThuis-adres: Rijmenam\nLid sinds 2012\nStudierichting: Elektronica-ICT\nContact: abactis.mereta@gmail.com" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVWouter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iVTom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iVTom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVTom"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/wouter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVQuaestor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVInfoAbactis"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVTom"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Quaestor: Wouter De Schutter"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVInfoQuaestor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVQuaestor"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVQuaestor"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Vulgo: &apos;der Schutz&apos;\nThuis-adreLid sinds 2010s: Muizen\nLid sinds 2010\nStudierichting: EM-Auto\nContact: quaestor.mereta@gmail.com" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVKyani"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iVWouter"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iVWouter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVWouter"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/kyani" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVFeestleider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVInfoQuaestor"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVWouter"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Feestleider: Kyani Vullings"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVInfoFeestleider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVFeestleider"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVFeestleider"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Kot-adres: Berthouders\nThuis-adres: Panningen\nLid sinds 2012\nStudierichting: OP\nContact: feestleider.mereta@gmail.com" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iVStef"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iVKyani"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iVKyani"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVKyani"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/stef" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVSpocul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVInfoFeestleider"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iVKyani"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Spocul: Stef Van Wolputte"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVInfoSpocul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tVSpocul"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVSpocul"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Kot-adres: Kot Leon\nThuis-adres: Herenthout\nLid sinds 2010\nStudierichting: Elektronica-Schakel\nContact: spocul.mereta@gmail.com\n" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the **main program:**

```
 package com.example.mereta;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView mImageGeschiedenis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    mImageGeschiedenis = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVGeschiedenis);
}

public void clickGeschiedenis(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mereta.Geschiedenis"));   
}

public void clickPraesidium(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mereta.Praesidium"));
}

public void clickKringlied(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mereta.KringLied"));
}

public void clickSponsors(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mereta.Sponsors"));
}

public void clickContact(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mereta.Contact"));
}

public void clickKalender(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mereta.Kalender"));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**This is the android manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mereta"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mereta.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name=".Geschiedenis"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mereta.Geschiedenis" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
                  <activity
        android:name=".Contact"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mereta.Contact" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
                  <activity
        android:name=".Kalender"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mereta.Kalender" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
                  <activity
        android:name=".KringLied"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mereta.KringLied" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
                  <activity
        android:name=".Praesidium"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mereta.Praesidium" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
                  <activity
        android:name=".Sponsors"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.mereta.Sponsors" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to implelemt Intent this way

```
   intent.setAction(this, SecondActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
   startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mereta.Geschiedenis"));
```

another thing try to add finish(); in each activity on back pressed 
so you will finish each activity when you start another